# I typed "python manage.py createsuperuser", however, the result was

Tags: visual-studio-code

C:\Users\kangs\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe: can't open file 'C:\djangosource\django_exam\manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

What should I do?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

you are not in the directory of this file `manage.py`,
so you need to make sure you are in the right place ,
to do that , do the following :
The manage.py file must be available at the root of the project folder.
so make sure `manage.py` where exist and if it is exist in  `django_exam` folder you need to `cd ..` in your command line then do this :

```
python manage.py createsuperuser
```